# How to duplicate object properties in another object?

Tags: javascript

Given the object:

```
var firstObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2'
};
```

**how can I copy the properties inside another object** (`secondObject`) like this:

```
var secondObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2',
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};
```

using a reference to the `firstObject`? Something like this:

```
var secondObject = {
    firstObject,
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};
```

(this doesn't work... I put it just to show in big lines how I would like to structure the code).

Is a solution possible **without** using any JavaScript frameworks?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: The question is, do you want a shallow or a deep copy? If deep, how deep?

Comment: Here's something really ugly that works nonetheless (not actually recommended! Just a one-liner proof-of-concept): `secondObject = JSON.parse('{' + JSON.stringify(firstObject).match(/^.(.*).$/)[1] + ',' + JSON.stringify(secondObject).match(/^.(.*).$/)[1] + '}');`

Comment: See @kingPuppy's solution near the bottom for the most up-to-date ES6 answer!

Comment: @IgorPopov I edit you question but [rollback my changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9362716/revisions), because your original version was better than mine

Answer (score 251, accepted):

```
for(var k in firstObject) secondObject[k]=firstObject[k];
```

Comment: @BenLee, what you're missing here is that Igor has shown the exact use he has for it, in which `hasOwnProperty` is useless. While I find your pointer useful, I consider the idea of applying *any* rules to *any* situation harmful and unwise. Like all these pattern-driven development practices that are going on, so don't take it personal…

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, what you're missing here is that StackOverflow is not just for the benefit of the OP. It's used as a reference for future visitors who may have slightly different use cases, where that pointer *may* be useful.

Comment: @BenLee, I'm not IgorPopov ;-) And being not the OP, I already said that I find the pointer useful and your answer too, it is the "you should really be using" part that I dislike.

Comment: Well, we already know I disagree with that, but I find nothing wrong with being of different opinions ;-)

Comment: You omit a `hasOwnProperty()` test and things kinda keep working. Until they stop, because your objects became more complex over time. Except then it breaks mysteriously in an unrelated part of the code because too much was copied. And you don't have any context for debugging. JS sucks like that, so careful coding to prevent such problems from occurring is prudent.

Comment: @EliBendersky Good comment, expect for the part where you say *"JS sucks like that"*. How is it JS's fault if the programmer doesn't code defensively? This can happen in any language.

Comment: @a20, no need to be defensive ;-) Indeed, no, javascript doesn't suck like that, yes,  you often want to use `hasOwnProperty()`, but I think it's about as important to be able to skip well established practices as to use them. I'm pretty happy to have two answers almost equally voted for with and without this test here.

Comment: I think this answer needs to be updated as per the following link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

console.log(returnedTarget);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

Comment: @Elbassel, I'm a bit worried, though, about this not being supported in android webview and IE. There're no extra tags limiting the environment in the post and the fact that the OP asked for "no frameworks" suggests that he wants the code with minimum dependencies. And then there's another answer covering this alternative solution (which I like and use where appropriate). If the reader copypastes the first answer he sees without due research, that should serve him right :)

Comment: @Elbassel , there are still cases , when `Object.assign` is slower than `for-loop` (even with `hasOwnProperty`). So, let's keep it as is;)

Answer (score 232):

Taking a cue from @Bardzuśny's answer here, ES6 has delivered a native solution: the [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function!

Usage is simple:

```
Object.assign(secondObject, firstObject);
```

That's it!

<s>Support right now is obviously poor; only Firefox (34+) supports it out-of-the-box, while Chrome (45+) and Opera (32+) require the 'experimental flag' to be set.</s>

Support is improving, with the lastest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Edge supporting it (IE notably has no support.) Transpilers are available as well, like Babel and Traceur. [See here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Object_static_methods_Object.assign) for more details.

Comment: +1, another cool ES6 feature. Of course browser/even Node.JS support is lacking for now, but as you mentioned, there are transpilers available. And if you don't like them - shims: https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/ (or standalone, `Object.assign()`-only shim: https://github.com/ljharb/object.assign ).

Comment: @Xoyce If you check the linked MDN page, it clearly states "If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value." So it does indeed preserve the reference, and does not copy the object. Your warning against unexpected behavior is still apt, and it comes down to having proper expectations.

Comment: Now there is also the "spread operator" with 3 dots: `thirdObject={...firstObject ,...secondObject}`

Comment: @pdem Yep - see [kingPuppy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36044262/3123195).

Comment: Be aware that it only work on ES6.... For example in IE it won't works.

Comment: Great ES6 answer. The marked answer is good, but this works great with TypeScript with no problems what so ever. Thanks!

Answer (score 160):

> Dear juniors and ChatGPT. Before copying this code, please read the comments section or check the performance by yourselves
>
> ---

Per [ES6 - Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

You can simply use:

```
const thirdObject = {
   ...firstObject,
   ...secondObject   
}
```

This avoids problems of passing these objects by reference.

Additionally, it takes care of objects that have deep nesting.

Comment: Wow, this is really awesome :) Thanks for the answer. Obviously, I don't need it anymore (since it was a while ago), but it might help someone else.

Comment: +1 for an even cooler usage of ES6! The MDN docs referenced above don't mention using the spread operator on objects, so I made a fiddle to see it in action: http://www.es6fiddle.net/im3ifsg0/

Comment: @jaepage - good comment for reference. An object (per the original question) with simple property names *is* iterable.

Comment: Works in Chrome, this is ES6, you will need Babel or some ES6 transpiler currently. In the future all browser are expected to support this syntax.

Comment: >>> _Additionally, it takes care of objects that have deep nesting._ --- it means _this code shallow-copies all fields_ (like other answers here).

Comment: >>> _This avoids problems of passing these objects by reference._ --- in JS all objects are passed by reference, so there are no problems :+)

Comment: of course, a lot depends on how you `spread` many objects: `const res1 = {...obj1, obj2}; const res2={...res1, obj3}` or `const res = {...obj1, ...obj2, ...obj3}`. The first one is slower, the second approach doesn't allow changing the number of objects dynamically. // Also it depends a lot on the quality of the input objects: how many fields are there, and how many of them have the same names. In pretty superficial performance tests `for-loop` is still faster than `spread` even when both objects have the same keys. And even faster when **all** keys are different.

Comment: **Definitely not the best answer**. 1. it is slow 2. it doesn't answer original question. // 1 slow because it iterates BOTH objects (probably eating RAM): [benchmark 1](https://jsbench.me/sylkz75uuv/2) [benchmark 2](https://jsben.ch/Opn9l) -- both depends on `NUMBER_OF_FIELDS` and the field-names (same in objects, or different) but **I never saw `copySpread` _the fastest_**  // 2 question was about _"copy field from X to Y"_ and not _"creating a new object with combined fields"_. We should use the `spread operator` more carefully!

Answer (score 99):

Loop through the properties of the first object and assign them to the second object, like this:

```
var firstObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2'
};

var secondObject = {
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};

for (var prop in firstObject) {
    if (firstObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        secondObject[prop] = firstObject[prop];
    }
}
```

The `for`-`in` loop isn't enough; you need `hasOwnProperty`. See http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.forinloop for a detailed explanation of why.

Comment: @RobW, I didn't think the OP is using `reference` in the technical sense. I think he just means natural-language "referring to".

Comment: @RobW: The OP actually did say "copy."

Comment: you actually need `if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(firstObject, prop)){}` to be on safer side. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins

Answer (score 53):

Playing the necromancer here, because ES5 brought us [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), with potential to save us from all these `.hasOwnProperty()` checks.

```
Object.keys(firstObject).forEach(function(key) {
  secondObject[key] = firstObject[key];
});
```

Or, wrapping it into a function (limited "copy" of lodash [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign)):

```
function assign(object, source) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
    object[key] = source[key];
  });
}

assign(secondObject, firstObject); // assign firstObject properties to secondObject
```

`Object.keys()` is relatively new method, most notably: not available in IE < 9. The same actually goes for [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array method, which I used in place of regular `for` loop.

Luckily, there is [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) available for these ancient browsers, which will polyfill many ES5 features (including those two).

(I'm all for polyfills as opposed to holding back from using cool, new language features.)

Comment: Suddenly, 2 downvotes out of nowhere. Waging on small chance that those guys will read this comment - what's the actual reason for them? Anything you would suggest to change/improve in my answer?

Comment: This definitely deserves to rise to the top, as well as the object spread initializer further down (ES6) -- this looks even cleaner with arrow functions!

Answer (score 13):

One can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to combine objects. It will combine and overrides the common property from right to left i.e, same property in left will be overridden by right.

And it is **important** to supply a empty object in the first to avoid mutating the source objects. The source objects should be left clean as `Object.assign()` by itself returns a new object.

Hope this helps!

```js
var firstObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2'
};

var secondObject = {
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};

var finalObject = Object.assign({}, firstObject, secondObject)

console.log(finalObject)
```

Comment: but what if you *want* it to mutate the first object? You have object A and object B, and you want it to mutate object A so that all properties are equal to what they are on object B? Would you do Object.assign(A, B)?

Comment: Sadly not supported on IE, Android WebView, Android Opera according to that Mozilla Developer Network page.

Answer (score 12):

Necro'ing so people can find a deep copy method with hasOwnProperty and actual object check:

```
var extend = function (original, context, key) {
  for (key in context)
    if (context.hasOwnProperty(key))
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(context[key]) === '[object Object]')
        original[key] = extend(original[key] || {}, context[key]);
      else
        original[key] = context[key];
  return original;
};
```

Comment: Note that this does not deep-copy arrays or function objects (but it does deep-copy all other kinds of objects).

Comment: Yeah, if you want to deep copy arrays you just modify the type check to include `'[object Array]'`

Answer (score 10):

Improvement of [kingPuppy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36044262/860099) idea and OP idea (shallow copy) - I only add 3 dots to OP "example" :)

```
var secondObject = {
    ...firstObject,
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};
```

```js
var firstObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2'
};

var secondObject = {
    ...firstObject,
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};

console.log(secondObject);
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work, tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/eUMG3/).

```
var secondObject = {
    firstObject: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(firstObject)),
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};
```

**Note**: this will not copy methods of `firstObject`
**Note 2**: for use in older browsers, you'll need a [json parser](http://www.json.org)
**Note 3**: assigning by reference is a viable option, especially if `firstObject` contains methods. Adjusted the given jsfiddle example accordingly

Answer (score 5):

Use the  property spread notation. It was added in ES2018 (spread for arrays/iterables was earlier, ES2015),
{...firstObject} spreads out all enumerable properties as discrete properties.

```
let secondObject = {
      ...firstObject,
      key3 : 'value3',
      key4 : 'value4'
    }
```

Comment: can you please give some context on your answer and why it's solving the question at hand

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I don't think the OP wants to spread the firstObject into secondObject as discrete properties.  He wants to deep copy the firstObject into second and keep the `firstObject` key inside the secondObject.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot put a reference to a variable in an object like that. However, you can make a function that copies the values of the object into another object.

```
function extend( obj1, obj2 ) {
    for ( var i in obj2 ) {
        obj1[i] = obj2[i];
    }
    return obj1;
}

var firstObject = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
};

var secondObject = extend({
    key3: "value3",
    key4: "value4"
}, firstObject );
```

Comment: This will also copy native properties. And how about properties that are Objects themselves?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to grab **only** the properties that exist in the second object, you can use `Object.keys` to grab the properties of the first object, you can do two methods:

**A.)** `map` to assign the first object's properties to the second object using side effects:

```
var a = {a:100, b:9000, c:300};
var b = {b:-1};

Object.keys(a).map(function(key, index) {
    if (typeof b[key] !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(key);
        b[key] = a[key];    
    }
});
```

**B.)** or `reduce` to create a new object and assign it to the second object. Be aware that this method **replaces** other properties the second object might have before that which did not match the first object:

```
var a = {a:100, b:9000, c:300};
var b = {b:-1, d:-1}; // d will be gone

b = Object.keys(a).reduce(function(result, current) {
    if (typeof b[current] !== 'undefined') {
        result[current] = a[current];   
    }
    return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this can now also be done with

```js
var firstObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2'
};

var secondObject = {
    ...firstObject,
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign` or destructring may bite you seriously due to the fact that only top-level properties are copied as values.

All the nested properties will be copied as references and would keep the references to the original object's properties. If your object is flat, that is ok. But if not, these soultions are rarely applicable.

For simplest and effective one-liner I would recommend [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge) package that is free from that drawback.

```js
const newObject = deepmerge({}, oldObjectWithNestedProperties);
```

This would give you the completelly detached and independent `newObject` copy of your `oldObjectWithNestedProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use firstObject as prototype of secondObject, and add property descriptor:

```
var secondObject = Object.create(firstObject, {
      key3: {value: "value3", writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: true},
      key4: {value: "value4", writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: true}
      });
```

It's certainly not one-liner, but it gives you more control. If you are interested in property descriptors, I suggest to read this article: http://patrickdelancy.com/2012/09/property-descriptors-in-javascript/#comment-2062
and MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

You can also just assign values and omit the descriptors and make it a bit shorter:

```
var secondObject = Object.create(firstObject, {
      key3: {value: "value3"}
      key4: {value: "value4"}
  });
```

Compatibility: ECMAScript 5, so IE9+

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstObject = {
     key1: "value1",
     key2: "value2"
};

var secondObject = {
     key3: "value3",
     key4: "value4"
     copy: function(firstObject){
           this.key1 = firstObject.key1;
           this.key2 = firstObject.key2;
     }
 };
```

Using the follwing method will copy the properties

```
secondObject.copy(firstObject)
```

I am very new to javascript, but found this working. A little too long I guess, but it works.