# How i can assign values to the properties of one object to another?

Tags: javascript

I have two objects like:

```
var a = { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', a3: {}}
var b = { a1: 'b1', a2: 'b2', a3: {}}
```

How i can assign values to the properties of one object to another?

If i try use `a=b` As I get an object a link to b. I just want to equate the value of the properties.

Comment: Are you trying to create a copy?

Comment: "Equate" how exactly? Do you just want to overwrite `b` with a clone of the object in `a` ?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to copy the object. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate object properties in another object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362716/how-to-duplicate-object-properties-in-another-object)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Object.assign()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/object/assign).

```
Object.assign(b, a); // Assign all properties of a to b. Changing b in the process.
```

Be advised: `Object.assign()` it relatively new, and is not supported in Internet Explorer as of yet.

A polyfill for it is available **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)**.

Comment: There's a polyfill for it to make it work in IE as well as older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill.

Comment: @MattBrowne Thanks, added. Next time, feel free to edit the post directly :)

Comment: `var b = Object.assign({}, a);`

Comment: @Tushar: That's not how I understood the question. Also, in this specific case, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot's of way to clone an object.

The two elegant (may not be the most efficient) ways are:

**Without** JQUERY - Using the serialize\deserialize way

```
var obj = { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', a3: {}}
var cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

**With** JQUERY - Using [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

```
var obj = { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2', a3: {}}
var cloned = $.extend({}, obj);
```

Comment: Lodash also has extend,defaults, and merge for this sort of thing.