# Is there any shorthand for binding interface constructor in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm new in typescript world and I know it is possible to bind arguments of constructor to the class like this

```
class user {
     constructor(private username:string){}
}
```

instead of

```
class user {
     constructor(username:string){
           this.username = username;
      }
 }
```

I just wonder is it possible to do similar thing with interfaces? for example:

```
interface IUser{
    username:string;
}

class User implements IUser  {
    constructor( private data:IUser ){
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Ryan  it's add data object to User so for access to username I have to go to this.data.username instead of this.username and obviously that's return error because User class doesn't implement IUser interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no shorthand. You will need to map the properties from the object being passed in to the instance of the class. You can do that in [a number of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362716/how-to-duplicate-object-properties-in-another-object). Here's an example:

```
class User implements IUser  {
    username: string;

    constructor(data: IUser) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
            this[key] = data[key];
        });
    }
}
```

Just be aware that in this example if the passed in object has additional properties then that will map those to your object as well.

By the way, a the shorter method is to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). `assign` is a new ES6 function on `Object`. You could use the polyfill found on the linked to site to make it work in runtime environments that don't support it.