# Copying properties from one object to another with a condition

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, assign

Lazy-me is wondering if there a better way to copy the properties in one object (source) over to another object (destination) only if the properties exist in the latter? It does not necessarily have to be using Underscore.

For example,

```
_.mixin({
    assign: function (o, destination, source) {
        for (var property in source) {
            if (destination.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                destination[property] = source[property];
            }
        }
        return destination;
    }
});

console.log( _().assign({ a: 1, b: 2, d: 3 }, { a: 4, c: 5 }) ) // a: 4, b: 2, d: 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate object properties in another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362716/how-to-duplicate-object-properties-in-another-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One lazy option is:

```
_.extend(a, _.pick(b, _.keys(a)));
```

`_.pick` filters the *source* object by using the *`.keys`* of the *destination* object and the result is used for extending the *destination* object.

If you don't want to modify the original objects just pass an empty object to the `_.extend` function.

```
_.extend({}, a, _.pick(b, _.keys(a)));
```

Comment: Haha, shorter but ugly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Object.assign(obj1, obj2);` (if the properties exist in the latter) which is native in ES6 (no underscore.js is required).

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object. It will return the target object. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Example:

```js
var o1 = { a: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj);
```

Alternatively use undescore.js

`_.extend(destination, *sources)`

or

`_.extendOwn(destination, *sources)`

Detailated information can be found here:
http://underscorejs.org/#extend

Comment: "...  only if the properties exist in the latter".

Comment: @Vohuman thanks for your comment I have edit a note in my answer for reference.