# Convert Javascript array of objects into one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have an array like this

```
var myarray=[{"id":1234, "listtext":open, "prop3":value3 ,"prop4": value4},
             {"id":1235, "listtext":open, "prop3":value3 ,"prop4": value4},
             {"id":1236, "listtext":open, "prop3":value3 ,"prop4": value4},
             {"id":1237, "listtext":open, "prop3":value3 ,"prop4": value4}];
```

but I want to convert it to an object like this:

```
{1234:open,1235:close, 1236: pending,1237:awaiting response}
```

Can this be done? all the methods I have tried keep getting only the last key value pair.

Comment: I want a key value pair of id and listtext properties only

Comment: I did that, and I am just getting the last value. e.g {4321:"some status"}

Comment: No offense, but your source data is rubbish.  Please try and include useful data in your questions so people don't have to try and guess at what you needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate object properties in another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362716/how-to-duplicate-object-properties-in-another-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using ES6 or above:

```
const converted = Object.assign({}, ...myArray.map(object => ({[object.id]: object})))
```

Comment: Thanks. My Initial solution was actually working. I just realized the ids are the same in my source data thats why I was getting only one key value pair.

Comment: what is this construct: `...myArray(object`?  It looks like you're using an array variable as if it's a function.  Is it some usage of spread or is there maybe a missing `.map`?

Comment: It is indeed the spread operator, used here to access the items in the array. Disclaimer: I did not come up with this myself ;-) Found this online somewhere and added it to my toolbelt. I find it to be a very useful oneliner

Comment: No, not the spread.  this part: `myArray(object`,  Executing it gives me "myArray is not a function"

Comment: Ah now I see the problem, you are right, I am indeed missing the map() function ;-) Thanks! Funny how this got accepted without anyone noticing the bug earlier ...

Answer (score 5):

You can simply loop over the array and create a new object

```js
var myarray=[{"id":1234, "listtext":'open', "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'},
             {"id":1235, "listtext":'open', "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'},
             {"id":1236, "listtext":'open', "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'},
             {"id":1237, "listtext":'open', "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'}];
const res = {};
myarray.forEach(obj => {
    res[obj.id] = obj.listtext;
})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: You have made a small mistake: you are using a const when you initiate the empty object

Comment: That's not really a mistake, though it might be confusing if ES6 is not being used. Assigning properties to a `const` object will work just fine.

Comment: @dentemm, since we are not reassigning res, we can declare it as a const obj

Comment: Ah yes indeed, my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myarray = [
  { id: 1234, listtext: 'open' },
  { id: 1235, listtext: 'closed' },
  { id: 1236, listtext: 'pending' },
  { id: 1237, listtext: 'open' }
]

var output = myarray.reduce(function (acc, item) {
  acc[item.id] = item.listtext
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. My Initial solution was actually working. I just realized the ids are the same in my source data thats why I was getting only one key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myarray=[{"id":1234, "listtext":"open", "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'},
             {"id":1235, "listtext":"closed", "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'},
             {"id":1236, "listtext":"pending", "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'},
             {"id":1237, "listtext":"open", "prop3":'value3' ,"prop4": 'value4'}];

var myObjects = [];  // create an empty array to hold the converted objects.


// loop through the array to convert them one by one
myarray.forEach(function(element) {
  var obj = {};    // create an empty object
  obj[element.id] = element.listtext;
  myObjects.push(obj);  // add the object to the array
});


myObjects.forEach(function(object){
   console.log(object);
});
```

Comment: How does this improve on @ShubhamKhatri's answer?

Comment: @Tibrogargan When I posted my answer, I was not aware someone else wrote the same exact answer

Comment: Thanks. My Initial solution was actually working. I just realized the ids are the same in my source data thats why I was getting only one key value pair.