# How to save and load objects with methods?

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects

Have a problem. I create my game object like this:

```
var game_status = {
    money          : 350000000,
    reset_status   : function() {
        this.money         = 350000000;
    }
}
function saveGame(){
    localStorage.setItem('game_status', JSON.stringify(game_status));
}
function loadGame(){
    game_status     = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game_status'));
}
```

After loading game status method "reset_status" doesn't exists anymore.

Probably I should describe object, create instance, save instance, and then loading creating instance anew with parameters from load?

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the stored state to the object:

```
Object.assign(game_status, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game_status')));
```

That way you don't have to write a constructor.

Comment: but is **game_status** a valid json?

Comment: @nullPointer yup, functions are removed on serialization, which is the wanted behaviour

Comment: MDN shows it's not supported by IE. Is there any workaround or another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since anyhow object state & object behavior lies within a simple hash and assuming what's needed here is a quick patch, I would do something like:

```
var INITIAL_GAME = {
    money          : 350000000
},
game_status; 

function saveGame(){
    // strip behavior
    delete game_status.resetGame;
    localStorage.setItem('game_status', JSON.stringify(game_status));

}
function loadGame(){
    game_status = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game_status'));
    if (!game_status) {
    // init by cloning initial object
        game_status = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(INITIAL_GAME));
    }
    // set behavior again
    game_status.resetGame = function resetGame() {
       this.money = 350000000;
    }
 }

 loadGame();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a notice, though. JSON.stringify() will drop any methods in object, so there is no need to delete object's methods.

Answer (score 0):

> for (var attrname in game_statusTemp) { game_status[attrname] =
>   game_statusTemp[attrname]; }

A quick workaround for my case. Found in
[How to duplicate object properties in another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362716/how-to-duplicate-object-properties-in-another-object) and [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)